# Plotband covered area columns to be highlighted or set opacity higher in highchart column type

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

I want to set opacity of a column which is covered in plotband area. Initially opacity of column is set to 0.4. When user selects particular plot area I need to change opacity of a column under plot area to be 1(i.e. original color) How can i achieve this.

[In image when user mouseover or clicks some column were selected, i want those columns to set it back it's original color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiBzS.jpg)

[JSFiddleEx](http://jsfiddle.net/girijsbin/sfykbss5/21/)

```
$(function() {

var plotbandclick = function(e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    //target.setAttribute('fill', '#e9e9e9');
    var classnames = target.getAttribute("class");
    if (classnames == null) {
        classnames = "";
    }
    var col = $(".plotbandactive");
    if (col.length > 0 && col != null) {
        col.attr("class", "");
    }
    console.log(classnames);
    if (classnames.indexOf("plotbandactive") == -1) {
        $(target).attr("class", classnames.trim() + " plotbandactive");
        //$(target).next().show();
    }
};

var plotbandmouseover = function showevent(e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    //target.setAttribute('fill', '#e9e9e9');
    var classnames = target.getAttribute("class");
    if (classnames == null) {
        classnames = "";
    }
    console.log(classnames);
    if (classnames.indexOf("plotbandhover") == -1) {
        $(target).attr("class", classnames.trim() + " plotbandhover");
        if (classnames.indexOf("plotbandactive") == -1) {
            //$(target).next().show();
        }
    }
};

var plotbandmouseout = function(e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    //target.setAttribute('fill', '#ffffff');
    var classnames = target.getAttribute("class");
    if (classnames == null) {
        classnames = "";
    }
    console.log(classnames);
    if (classnames.indexOf("plotbandhover") > -1) {
        classnames = classnames.replace("plotbandhover", "");
        $(target).attr("class", classnames.trim());
        if (classnames.indexOf("plotbandactive") == -1) {
            //$(target).next().hide();
        }
    }
};

Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M', x, y + width / 2, 'L', x + height, y + width / 2];
};



var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Trend charts'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['ERIF001', 'ERIF002', 'CRIF001', 'CRIF002', 'EPVIF001'],
        tickLength: 0,
        /*lineColor: '#fff',
        lineWidth: 3,*/
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        plotBands: [{
            color: '#ffffff',
            label: {
                text: 'Section 1'
            },
            from: -0.5,
            to: 0.5,
            events: {
                click: plotbandclick,
                mouseover: plotbandmouseover,
                mouseout: plotbandmouseout
            }
        }, {
            color: '#ffffff',
            label: {
                text: 'Section 2'
            },
            from: 0.5,
            to: 2.5,
            events: {
                click: plotbandclick,
                mouseover: plotbandmouseover,
                mouseout: plotbandmouseout
            }
        }, {
            color: '#ffffff',
            label: {
                text: 'Employee Preventable - EPVIF'
            },
            from: 2.5,
            to: 4.5,
            events: {
                click: plotbandclick,
                mouseover: plotbandmouseover,
                mouseout: plotbandmouseout
            }
        }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        tickColor: '#fff',
        tickWidth: 1,
        tickLength: 3,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        endOnTick: true,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        max: 150
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
        shared: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'percent',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<div style="text-align:center"><div>' + this.y + '</div><div><img src="http://placehold.it/' + (this.y == 0 ? '5' : this.y * 2) + '/' + (this.y == 0 ? '5' : this.y * 2) + '"></div></div>';
                },
                y: 0
            }
        },
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                symbol: 'line',
                lineWidth: 15,
                radius: 38,
                lineColor: '#993300'
            }
        },
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Measure',
        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Target',
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [82, 82, 82, 82, 82]
    }, {
        name: 'Measure',
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Target',
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
    }, {
        name: 'Measure',
        color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Target',
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [18, 18, 18, 18,18]
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this idea:

- First, give the plot bands a higher `zIndex` by default (say, `zIndex: 10`). This will place them on top of the columns.
- Next, change the color of the plot bands to white and set the opacity to `0.4`. This will give you the "faded" look you have in your image example.
- Whenever the user hovers over (`mouseover`) or clicks on a column, change the `zIndex` of that specific plot band to 0 (moving it back under the column), change the color to gray, and set the opacity to `1`.
- When the user moves their mouse off the column (`mouseout`), go back to the `zIndex` of 10, the white color, and the 0.4 opacity.

Let me know what you think!

> **Update (May 31, 2016)**: As @GiriDeshi noted, it doesn't seem as though you can
>   directly change the `zIndex` value for the plot bands when an event is
>   fired. Here's my alternate solution:

- Let's set the plot bands to a z-index of 10 by default and change the color to an `rbga` value with an opacity of 80%:

  ```
      plotBands: [{
          color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
          label: {
              text: 'Section 1'
          },
          from: -0.5,
          to: 0.5,
          events: {
              click: plotbandclick,
              mouseover: plotbandmouseover,
              mouseout: plotbandmouseout
          },
          zIndex: 10
      }, {
  ```
- Next, let's set a plot background color for the chart itself:

  ```
  chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      defaultSeriesType: 'column',
      plotBackgroundColor: '#e9e9e9'
  },
  ```
- Then, let's change the color of the active and hover styles for the plot bands:

  ```
  path.plotbandactive
  {
      fill: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  }
  path.plotbandhover
  {
      fill: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  }
  ```

This will result in the following:

- By default, the white plot bands are sitting over the columns, giving the "faded" effect.
- When a user hovers over the plot band, it's opacity changes to zero, so both the column and the gray background (now applied to the entire chart background) shows through.
- When the user moves their cursor off the plot band, it goes back to the "faded" effect.

Here's an updated version of the fiddle with these changes http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/sfykbss5/24/

[image]

Comment: Plotbands cannot be made visible always to set as zIndex, Is there a way to access columns  under plotted area so that i can reset those 3 series columns back to opacity 1.

Comment: @GiriDeshi You're right! I took another look at your code and updated my answer with an alternate solution. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Awesome, it works great. Will check with team for approval.

Comment: got a problem. I want to raise an events on clicking of column. z-index is preventing it from raising events. How can raise child events.

Comment: @GiriDeshi I added a test `alert` call to your `plotbandclick` function, and was able to see it OK. Are your child events going to happen outside of `plotbandclick`?

Comment: Plotband z-index is preventing me to click events of columns(those red, yellow & green). It's by design but is there a work around for it.

Comment: @GiriDeshi Not as it's been reworked so far, unfortunately .. all the z-index swapping to get the desired effect does remove the ability to interact with the individual column segments. You may want to look at this type of column chart (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement) and see whether you could try using non-interactive columns for the gray backgrounds.